# How can I determine if an organization is using NAT?

Tags: networking

As far as I understand, I can tell if an organisation is using NAT if they are using private IP address space.

It can be determined that an organization is using private IP address space if its addresses fall into the following ranges, reserved for private uses by Internet standards groups:

- 10.0.0.0 through 10.255.255.255
- 169.254.0.0 through 169.254.255.255 (APIPA only)
- 172.16.0.0 through 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.255.255

Am I correct.....? Please correct the logic if it is not correct.

Comment: Are you trying to determine from the address alone if you're behind a NAT? Because that's not going to work. What information do you have available to you? For example, do you have the ability to talk to a [server on the internet](http://www.whatismyip.com/) which could report back your "apparent IP address"? (hint: if it reports an address not assigned to one of your interfaces, you're behind a NAT or other proxy) Are you working on client or server side code?

Comment: If they use NAT then you dont get the private IP addresses in the packets. Instead, you get natted IP addresses. So, using the IP addresses alone is not enough. IKE peers send hashes of IP+port and compare the hashes to see if NAT translator was present in the path. You can check NAT-T for more details.

Answer (score 1):

While you are basically correct about which space is considered "private" (see [RFC 1918 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#section-3)), I do not think you can make this assumption in your program, for the following reasons:

- An organization might be using private addresses, but not be using NAT at all (for example, a completely private intranet)
- An organization might be using NAT, but with a reserved public subnet. (Yes, I have seen organizations with IP address space to burn do this.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is practically incomprehensible, but taking this from the title:

> How will i get to know if organisation is using NAT?

You can't.

Comment: That's not exactly correct. There are some tricks that can be used to determine if a NAT is in use. For example, [this is how IPsec does it](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3947#section-3.2). This is, of course, assuming the original poster has control of some kind of protocol running between the two hosts. ;-)